# XSLT Error: xmlParseEntityRef

Tags: xslt, rss, umbraco

I seem to be getting this problem every time I cerate a new RSS feed, I just click new RSS feed, then bang this error comes up, I haven't messed with the xslt so I don't know what's causing the problem.

This page contains the following errors:
error on line 31 at column 36: xmlParseEntityRef: no name
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Does anyone have any idea what is causing the problem?

here is the XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:rssdatehelper="urn:rssdatehelper"
  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
  xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
  xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
  xmlns:umbraco.library="urn:umbraco.library" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltCommon="urn:Exslt.ExsltCommon" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes="urn:Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltMath="urn:Exslt.ExsltMath" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions="urn:Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltStrings="urn:Exslt.ExsltStrings" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltSets="urn:Exslt.ExsltSets" xmlns:fulltextsearch.search="urn:fulltextsearch.search" xmlns:fulltextsearch.helper="urn:fulltextsearch.helper" xmlns:PS.XSLTsearch="urn:PS.XSLTsearch" 
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxml umbraco.library Exslt.ExsltCommon Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes Exslt.ExsltMath Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions Exslt.ExsltStrings Exslt.ExsltSets fulltextsearch.search fulltextsearch.helper PS.XSLTsearch ">


  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:param name="currentPage"/>

  <!-- Update these variables to modify the feed -->
  <xsl:variable name="RSSNoItems" select="string('10')"/>
  <xsl:variable name="RSSTitle" select="string('....')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="SiteURL" select="string('/news/')"/>
  <xsl:variable name="RSSDescription" select="string('....')"/>

  <!-- This gets all news and events and orders by updateDate to use for the pubDate in RSS feed -->
  <xsl:variable name="pubDate">

    <xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/* [@isDoc]">   

      <xsl:sort select="@createDate" data-type="text" order="descending" />
      <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="updateDate" />
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- change the mimetype for the current page to xml -->
    <xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:ChangeContentType('text/xml')"/>

    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;</xsl:text>
    <rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
>

      <channel>
        <title>
          <xsl:value-of select="$RSSTitle"/>
        </title>
        <link>
          <xsl:value-of select="$SiteURL"/>
        </link>
        <pubDate>
          <xsl:value-of select="$pubDate"/>
        </pubDate>
        <generator>umbraco</generator>
        <description>
          <xsl:value-of select="$RSSDescription"/>
        </description>
        <language>en</language>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="$currentPage/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']">
          <xsl:sort select="@createDate" order="descending" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </channel>
    </rss>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="* [@isDoc]">
    <xsl:if test="position() &lt;= $RSSNoItems">
      <item>
        <title>
          <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
        </title>
        <link>
          <xsl:value-of select="$SiteURL"/>
          <xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)"/>
        </link>
        <pubDate>
          <xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:FormatDateTime(@createDate,'r')" />
        </pubDate>
        <guid>
          <xsl:value-of select="$SiteURL"/>
          <xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)"/>
        </guid>
        <content:encoded>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;![CDATA[ ', ./bodyText,']]&gt;')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        </content:encoded>
      </item>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: More likely problem is in XML.

Answer (score 3):

Your stylesheet contains a lot of processor-specific extensions so I can't run it but I would guess that it is reporting an error in the source file not in the stylesheet, most likely an unquoted `&` rather than `&amp;`.